# Start point for creating a new application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I need to create an application in C# Windows Forms that uses database to store, display and manage some informations, let`s say personal data of some company employees (e.g display it, change, add new). I need advices where to start, which books are good (preferably not too old). I want to use Entity Framework 4.1. I have experience in OO programming (java), but am new to .NET and i wrote mainly console applications (in java).
Please share your recommendations.

Comment: There is no book about EF 4.1.

Comment: Ok. Which one would you reccomend for winforms?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't use WinForms for about 5 years. I can only answer part about Entity framework.

Comment: Ok, thanks, if you can add something about EF, please do so.

Comment: EF 4.1 is still pretty new so there is not many information you must google a lot or search here on SO. Good start is ADO.NET team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/ and Morteza Manavi's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/default.aspx I'm also planning some articles about mapping in EF 4.1 but I haven't started yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

I find the **[Beginner Developer Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308806.aspx)** to be extremely helpful starting out with C#. You can jump to the appropriate tier for your skill level:

- **Tier One:** The introduction provides some basics of  and gets you started using Visual Studio Express
- **Tier Two:** This section moves more into creating a user interface, OO, and .NET
- **Tier Three:** Here you touch on working with databases, XML, and exception handling